# ANR on com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild

Tags: android

I just noticed that Google has improved some of their ANR reports, I now see a new ANR I haven't seen before. The title is `com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild` and the stack trace is below. What would be causing that? is the `AppBar` my entire top bar? does it include my hamburger menu? This ANR is on my top 20 so I would prefer to not ignore it.

```
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.SolverVariableValues.getVariable (SolverVariableValues.java:63)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.PriorityGoalRow.updateFromRow (PriorityGoalRow.java:247)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.SolverVariable.updateReferencesWithNewDefinition (SolverVariable.java:214)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.LinearSystem.addRow (LinearSystem.java:609)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.LinearSystem.addConstraint (LinearSystem.java:589)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.LinearSystem.addEquality (LinearSystem.java:1220)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.applyConstraints (ConstraintWidget.java:2690)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.addToSolver (ConstraintWidget.java:2151)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.addChildrenToSolver (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:330)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:489)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem (BasicMeasure.java:130)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:366)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.onMeasure (CardView.java:260)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure (ConstraintLayout.java:763)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure (BasicMeasure.java:426)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:335)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins (ScrollView.java:1308)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure (ScrollView.java:350)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure (ConstraintLayout.java:763)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure (BasicMeasure.java:426)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:335)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (AppBarLayout.java:2227)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:831)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1156)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6602)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:724)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22082)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2426)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1508)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1765)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6773)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:966)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:778)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:713)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:952)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6518)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Hey, any update? I am facing the same

Comment: No. I even rewrote the xml on where I thought it was, I switched from a bunch of nested `LinearLayouts` to `ConstraintsLayout` and it didn't help.